# How to use a @variable with min/max functions?

Tags: mysql

**Edit:** narrowed the problem down. here's a simpler example:

```
mysql> select * from table_a;
+-------+
| col_a |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
|     4 |
+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @a:=max(col_a),@a from table_a;
+----------------+------+
| @a:=max(col_a) | @a   |
+----------------+------+
|              4 | NULL |
+----------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why is `@a` `NULL`, and how can I get it to *not* be?

Comment: I made a foolish mistake when testing that alias thing which gave me a false positive result, deleted the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MySql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) is quite clear about this, quote:

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and may change based on the elements contained within a given statement; in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between releases of the MySQL Server. In SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ..., you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second. However, changing the statement (for example, by adding a GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY clause) may cause MySQL to select an execution plan with a different order of evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

*would not every column return by aggregate function can be used for most of the cases?*

in another words, is hard to *guess* what you are truly looking for
(dun mind to update your question again?)

the normal usage

```
select max(col_a) as anything
from table_a
order by anything;
```

i dun see any harm for this either

```
select max(col_a) as anything, max(col_a) as anything2, 
from table_a
order by anything, anything2;
```

if you are trying to use the aggregate function for `LIMIT`,
this is not doable

user defined variables from select is not reliable (I *used* to be a fan)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

> As a general rule, **you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement**. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and may change based on the elements contained within a given statement; in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between releases of the MySQL Server. In SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ..., you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second. However, changing the statement (for example, by adding a GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY clause) may cause MySQL to select an execution plan with a different order of evaluation.

Comment: huh..? can you explain this a bit more? `stamp_date` is an `INT` that stores a unix timestamp. I want to put `MIN(stamp_date)` into a variable because I need to re-use a bunch of times in my query. Your query doesn't even make reference to `MIN(stamp_date)`. Oh.......you're lopping off the first stamp_date which will be the min, aren't you? Why would that work, but `min` not?

Comment: Ok, you're `substring_index` craziness does indeed retrieve the same value that `MIN` did, but I don't see how this resolves anything. I still can't throw it in a variable and re-use it.

Comment: once you have the start_time value, you can use start_time for sorting

Comment: but i don't just want to use it for sorting, i want to use it to fetch other fields. and i could have done that with `max()` as well. i still don't see what this accomplishes.